# Passing a Button Component to the Title prop of a Bootstrap Tab Component

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using the react-bootstrap Tab component and wish to include a button in the tab title. To set the text of the title you must pass the desired text as props. I want to include a button to remove the tab, appearing next to the text.

I have tried passing a function that returns the button element, but nothing displays in the tab title.

```
<Tab eventKey={data.name} title={data.name}>
    <Button 
         className={classes.Button} 
         variant="secondary" 
         onClick={() => removeData({ id: data.id })}
         >X</Button>
    <TemplateTabs name={data.name} />
 </Tab>
```

Right now the above code renders the button inside the tab page, whereas the desired location would be in the tab title. The template tabs component is what displays in the tab page. Ideally, I am looking for a way to continue to use the react-bootstrap Tab component, but be able to render the tab title and button to remove the said tab. Below is the documentation for the Tab component I am implementing from react-bootstrap. Please let me know if any more information would be useful.

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/tabs/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation says type `node`: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/tabs/#tab-props

So this *should* work:

```
<Tab
    eventKey={data.name}
    title={
        <>
            {data.name}
            <Button
                className={classes.Button}
                variant="secondary"
                onClick={() => removeData({ id: data.id })}>
                X
            </Button>
        </>
    }>
    <TemplateTabs name={data.name} />
</Tab>
```